# Android: How do I figure out which package provides a service?

Tags: android, android-source

On android, I can see a service running with `service list`:

Let's say:

```
# service list | grep dropbox
87  dropbox: [com.android.internal.os.IDropBoxManagerService]
```

How do I map this to the APK that is serving it?

Answer (score 0):

These are system services, and are part of the system server.
App services don't show here.
Note that dropbox service is not related to the Dropbox commercial service.

The way to go to the code would be to simply search for that name on the codebase. If you don't have AOSP checkout, you can use https://cs.android.com

For your example, this is the code:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/DropBoxManagerService.java;l=52?q=IDropBoxManagerService&sq=

Comment: Thanks. How do I know if a service is provided by a system service or by a package (APK)?

Comment: That command only shows system services. If you want to query about app services, you may want to use adb shell dumpsys activity services

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check "Services component" in apks.

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services
```

P.S. `dropbox` is a system service, and system services are totally different things with service components in apk.